# change Jquery UI fonts with @fontface

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui, fonts, font-face

I'd like to change the font-family used by Jquery UI to web font using @fontface. I have created my own css file, named *my.css* and I supplied it with the follwoing CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Conv_mry_KacstQurn";
    src: url('fonts/mry_KacstQurn.eot#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('fonts/mry_KacstQurn.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/mry_KacstQurn.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/mry_KacstQurn.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

body *{
font-family: "Conv_mry_KacstQurn";
}
```

The code of my page header section is as the follwoing:

```
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>jQuery UI Example Page</title>
<link type="text/css" href="css/my.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link type="text/css" href="css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.min.js"></script>


        <script type="text/javascript">
/* initiation of UI code */
</script>
<style type="text/css">
            /*demo page css*/
            body{ font: 62.5% "Conv_mry_KacstQurn", sans-serif; margin: 50px;}
            .demoHeaders { margin-top: 2em; }
            #dialog_link {padding: .4em 1em .4em 20px;text-decoration: none;position: relative;}
            #dialog_link span.ui-icon {margin: 0 5px 0 0;position: absolute;left: .2em;top: 50%;margin-top: -8px;}
            ul#icons {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
            ul#icons li {margin: 2px; position: relative; padding: 4px 0; cursor: pointer; float: left;  list-style: none;}
            ul#icons span.ui-icon {float: left; margin: 0 4px;}
        </style>
    </head>
```

Using body * in my.css makes everything well and the web font is rendered in the Jquery UI elements as well. **The problem is when I want to use multiple font families in the page. So I want to know how to set a web font to be used with Jquery UI elements without using body * selector?**

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all viewer, I had find the answer. Simply, it includes to replace the order of the two linked css files to be:

```
     <link type="text/css" href="css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link type="text/css" href="css/my.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Then copying the follwoing CSS rules from css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.css and then pasting them in my.css with adding the font-family I want to the font-family properties found there:

```
 * Component containers
    ----------------------------------*/
    .ui-widget { font-family: "Conv_mry_KacstQurn",Verdana,Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 1.1em; }
    .ui-widget .ui-widget { font-size: 1em; }
    .ui-widget input, .ui-widget select, .ui-widget textarea, .ui-widget button { font-family: "Conv_mry_KacstQurn",Verdana,Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 1em; }
    .ui-widget-content { border: 1px solid #a6c9e2; background: #fcfdfd url(images/ui-bg_inset-hard_100_fcfdfd_1x100.png) 50% bottom repeat-x; color: #222222; }
    .ui-widget-content a { color: #222222; }
    .ui-widget-header { border: 1px solid #4297d7; background: #2191c0 url(images/ui-bg_highlight-hard_75_2191c0_1x100.png) 50% 50% repeat-x; color: #eaf5f7; font-weight: bold; }
    .ui-widget-header a { color: #eaf5f7; }
```

That's all, and now all Jquery elements have the font-family that I want.